# How to decrypt message using CryptoJS-DES

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am using CryptoJs for encryption and decryption. Here I am having a bit of problem which is I have given this code which is used to convert the message into encrypted but having a problem to convert encrypted message to decrypt.

Maybe they are using their own secret key but have not placed it correctly

https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

See in Custom Key and IV section

From here I get to know how to change the key but the problem is the where should I apply the change.

This is the code--

My HTML file

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="tripledes.js"></script>
  <script src="mode-ecb.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

  function viewvalue()
  {
  var message = document.getElementById("msg").value;
  var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
  var encrypted = encryptByDES(message, key);
  document.getElementById("enctext").textContent = encrypted;
  document.getElementById("dectxt").textContent = decryptByDES(encrypted, key);;


  }

  function encryptByDES(message, key) {

  var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  });
  return encrypted.toString();
  }

  function decryptByDES(ciphertext, key) {
  var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
  ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext)
  }, keyHex, {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  });

  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="maindiv">
  <div>
  <label for="name">Message:</label>
  <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="mail">Key:</label>
  <input type="text" id="key" name="key" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="msg">Encrypted Text:</label>
  <textarea id="enctext" name="enctxt"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="msg">Decrypted Text:</label>
  <textarea id="dectxt" name="dectxt"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
  <button onclick="viewvalue()">View</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is .js file

```
  /*
  CryptoJS v3.1.2
  code.google.com/p/crypto-js
  (c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
  code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
  */
  /**
  * Electronic Codebook block mode.
  */
  CryptoJS.mode.ECB = (function () {
  var ECB = CryptoJS.lib.BlockCipherMode.extend();

  ECB.Encryptor = ECB.extend({
  processBlock: function (words, offset) {
  this._cipher.encryptBlock(words, offset);
  }
  });

  ECB.Decryptor = ECB.extend({
  processBlock: function (words, offset) {
  this._cipher.decryptBlock(words, offset);
  }
  });

  return ECB;
  }());
```

They are also using tripledes min file.

I have been told to change the key value in HEX and then hard-code that value in code but where to hard code the value as this is what the code is doing. It is taking the value given in Key and changing it to HEX value than the message according to that.

But what it is not doing is convert any encrypted message to plain text.

I am very much confused why it is not able to decrypt the encrypted message.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Please do not post unnecessary CSS. Only post a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: yeah updated the file

Comment: For a better suggestion, use https which is better than using js base encryption. if others can visit your site, they also can get your js file.

Comment: its just for testing...

Comment: @shv22 If you hardcode the key, then this is nothing more than obfuscation. If you want real security, then you would need to deliver the whole site over HTTPS, but then you wouldn't need CryptoJS anymore.

Comment: Are you really just asking how to hardcode a key into the code? I don't understand what the issue is. You would encode the key to hex, store it in a string and then parse it with `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexEncodedKeyString)`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Problem is how I would get the encrypted text converted to unencrypted...

Comment: @ArtjomB. it is just for testing purpose..we are not able to convert the encrypted data response back to plain text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114514/discussion-between-shv22-and-artjom-b).

Comment: It is working other way round but not from encrypted to plain text...

Comment: Ok, but I just tried your code and it is working correctly. So, what's the issue? Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4roqa2et/

Comment: How do you create the ciphertext then?

Comment: Ciphertext can be created by using this but when you place ciphertext in message or inplace of encrypted message again to decrypt what it will do is it will think of that message again as encrypted and convert that message again

Comment: I need to convert a encrypted message to plain text...how can I do that?

Comment: So, you're asking how to split the "view" button into an "encrypt" and "decrypt" button?

Comment: yes..how to get encrypted message and decrypted message view differently and user should be asked which value he wants to view either encypted or decrypted